# Non-Administrator domain account cannot remote managing Hyper-V 2016 core

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V 2016 core server installed. We can authenticate using the Hyper-V Manager with the network domain account. We want to use the 'BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrator' group to delegate access. 
Currently, using GPO we have a test user assigned via Restricted Groups to 'BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrator' and 'BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users'
The test account can access local Hyper-V instances but cannot access the remote hyper-v server through Hyper-V Manager on a local client.
The account is able to RDP to it and obtain the CMD/Powershell terminals. We also confirmed that the account shows up in 'net localgroup Hyper-V Administrators'
What other settings need to be configured to assign this role?

Update1-2018-08-17
Here is the current localgroup and domain group settings from the Hyper-V Administrators groups
[Group settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Q80.png) 
I am able to remotely login with the Hyper-V Manager using the Domain Administrator successfully, but when using the 'stefan' domain account it fails with the following
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxAOo.png) 
The powershell cmd 'Enable-PSRemoting -Force' was run and the server was rebooted already.
The users in the 'Hyper-V Administrators' account are able to run Hyper-V Manager on their local machines without an issue.

Comment: What error message do you get?  Have you checked the points in <[this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts)>, e.g., checked that Powershell Remoting is enabled and that the Hyper-V Manager version is compatible?  There's also a <[comment here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2014/06/11/allowing-non-administrators-to-control-hyper-vupdated/)> from someone saying they had to reboot the host after adding the user to Hyper-V Administrators.

Comment: @HarryJohnston
I've followed the microsoft document and already had PSRemoting enabled. See my Update1 for screenshots/details

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but you might try making `stefan` administrative on the client machine and see if that makes any difference.  You'll need to reboot the client.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work.
The Domain User needs to be added to the following local groups. 
Which can be done via GPO 'Restricted Groups'

BUILTIN\Hyper-V Administrators
BUILTIN\Remote Management Users
BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users

Do a gpupdate /force on the Hyper-V server afterwards